# Способы подключения к базе Mysql и их минусы при помощи Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, mvc

В документации к Express можно найти следующий фрагмент кода

```
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'dbuser',
  password : 's3kreee7'
});

connection.connect();

connection.query('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution', function(err, rows, fields) {
  if (err) throw err;
  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0].solution);
});

connection.end();
```

Расскажите пожалуйста, насколько такой подход безопасен (от инъекций и нагрузке в реальных проектах) и в каком виде нужно его хранить в корне папки сервера. Лучше всегда разбивать на модули (по MVC) и по файлам, и как к этому прийти?

Comment: А при чем здесь проверка соединения связи с БД с MVC? Всё что здесь делается это подсоединение к БД, вычисление тестового запроса и закрытие связи без использования каких либо параметров.

Comment: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/v3/